# Returning value of type defined in a class template

Tags: c++, class, templates, visual-c++, return-type

I'm new to C++ and trying to return a value from the `size()` member of my `X` class; the return type must be of `X::size_type`.

```cpp
template <class T> class X {
public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    size_type size() const;
    // ...
}

template <class T> X<T>::size_type X<T>::size() const {
    // ...
}
```

The above code results in errors. I added `typename` before `X<T>::size_type` and the issue seems to be fixed but I don't understand why...

Is this the right way?

Comment: Yes, typename is correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the complex and sometimes ambiguous syntax of C++, sometimes hints are needed for the parser/compiler.

In general when referring to types defined inside a class, `typename` is needed to hint the compiler that you're talking about a type and not a value (since `X<T>::size_type` can be either).